# What is a good way to assign order #s to ordered rows in a table in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, rowcount

I have a table T (structure below) which initially contains all-NULL values in an integer **`order`** column:

```
col1  varchar(30),
col2  varchar(30),
order int NULL
```

I also have a way to order the "colN" columns, e.g.

`SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY some_expression_involving_col1_and_col2`

**What's the best way to assign - IN SQL - numeric order values 1-N to the order table, so that the order values match the order of rows returned by the above ORDER BY**?

In other words, I would like a single query (Sybase SQL syntax so no Oracle's rowcount) which assigns `order` values so that `SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY order` returns 100% same order of rows as the query above.

The query does NOT necessarily need to update the table T in place, I'm OK with creating a copy of the table T2 if that'll make the query simpler.

NOTE1: A solution must be real query or a set of queries, **not** involving a loop or a cursor.

NOTE2: Assume that the data is uniquely orderable according to the order by above - no need to worry about situation when 2 rows can be assigned the same order at random.

NOTE3: I would prefer a generic solution, but if you wish a specific example of ordering expression, let's say:

```
SELECT * FROM T 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col1="" THEN "AAAAAA" ELSE col1 END, ISNULL(col2, "ZZZ")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used as an example the roysched table in pubs2. I added a column `id` (int NULL) and used as an ordering logic the following:

```
substring(title_id,3,4) + right(replicate('0',5) + convert(varchar,lorange),5)
```

Then I created (and updated) a view. To avoid duplicating, I used strings

```
Declare @strSql varchar(1000), @strOrder varchar(256)
set @strOrder = "substring(title_id,3,4) + right(replicate('0',5) + convert(varchar,lorange),5)"

set @strSql = "create view my_roysched (id,my_order)
as 
select id, (select count(*) from (select " + @strOrder + " as my_order from roysched) BETA 
              where BETA.my_order <= ALPHA.my_order) as my_id 
      from (select id," + @strOrder + " as my_order from roysched ) as ALPHA 

update my_roysched 
set id = my_order

drop view my_roysched"

exec (@strSql)
```

Now if you give

```
select * from roysched
order by substring(title_id,3,4) + right(replicate('0',5) + convert(varchar,lorange),5)
```

you will see that id match the order of rows returned by the above order by

Comment: Neat! I'm not 100% I can use this (I need t evaluate performance considerations on doing this repeatedly) but it's impressive technically nonetheles! +1

Answer (score 1):

DVK

People have answered your specific question, and you have chosen an answer.

But the whole issue has a deeper problem.

1. From what I can understand, the `Order` is a column in the table; which identifies the Order in which the rows are to be presented (or similar).  Is that correct ?
2. If so, then the table is massively denormalised: you have broken 3NF (Functional Dependency rule is broken); you have a derived value in a column (duplicated information); introduced Update Anomalies (when you update data in a column, you now need to update the duplicated [dependent] data in another column).
3. The most important of those is of course the Update Anomalies.  You can no longer insert a row into the (now non-relational, unnormalised) table.  For every insert, you have to recalculate and UPDATE the `Order` column for at least one and at most **every other row** in the table.
4. None of that is necessary.

   - I could answer your question within the scope of your question only, to populate the `Order` column (to be called by the code segment that constantly maintains it).  The code required is 5 lines. Pure standard SQL on the base table.  No views. No temp tables. No loops or cursors. Works the same as the Oracle `RANK()` function, and is therefore generic (just substitute your table and column names).
   - but the point is, that is the same code that could and would be used at runtime to produce the `Order` column, if it was a Derived Value, not a real column in the database.  So again, the `Order` column, and **all** the code required to maintain it, can be removed.
   - therefore I may as well give you the code to produce the Order or Rank [derived] value directly from your base tables, without regard to the Order column.
5. Following that, the assignment of `Order` is trivial.  Another way of stating that is, I would replace your first `SELECT`, and perform both functions in one code segment; there is no need for the `COUNT()` as a separate code segment.

Are you interested ?

In which case I need to know the exact `col_N` types, and what the `Order` value is based on, eg. highest Student Mark.  Table Definition (obfuscated) is easier.

### Response to Comments

1. Well, if it is a temp table, there is a much easier way, a different approach:

   - Give it an `Order` column
   - define it as `IDENTITY`
   - ensure the `SELECT` you use to populate it has the correct `ORDER BY`
     .
2. Do you still need the `Order` computed ?
   If so, pardon me, I don't know how to make this sound more nice. I realise you **think**  I do not need to know the answer to my question; but the code I use is **beyond that threshold**, otherwise you would have coded it by now (you seem to have some experience SQL and Sybase).

   I am  not "drafting", I have had the code for 20 years.  In each instance, I just have to plug in the specific table and column names, takes 10 seconds.  Therefore I do know what the code needs (as in, I understand the logical principle the code uses, the code itself is dead simple).  And of course there are variations, because it is a logical solution, not merely a piece of clever code: one person wants Students ranked by Mark; someone else wants two columns with the second one `DESCending`.

   - It always takes longer to explain the problem, than to fix it.
   - Eg. you have 2 columns (the description is fine, thanks). But you are asking for an ordinal, which (by definition) requires only one column or aggregate. Imagine an Unique Clustered Index on `(col_1, col2)`, which is what you are saying the `Order` needs to identify. I do not understand why is `col_2` relevant.  If the ordinal for the row where `col_1` is "KKKKKK" is 12345, then the ordinal for the row is "KKKKKL" will have to be 12346; regardless of what `col_2` is, in either of those two rows.  It is the leading column of the index.
   - The code I supply has to take whatever you are **logically** doing in that `ORDER BY` clause into account.  Otherwise it will be "unfinished" or "incomplete", and you still have to mess with it; which is not going to be fair to you because you do not understand the logical principle behind it.
   - Then you have the complication due to the use of `VARCHARs`, which is easy to code around, but I need to know what it is.  Using my Clustered Index visualisation, which of these four is correct ?  Do I need `LTRIM()` ?
     `( col_1 , col2)`
     `( CONVERT( CHAR(30), col_1 ) , CONVERT( CHAR(30), col_2 ) )`
     `( col_1 + col_2 )  -- as varchars`
     `( CONVERT( CHAR(30), col_1 ) + CONVERT( CHAR(30), col_2 ) )`

Cheers

Comment: while the above concern with breaking 3NF is true for real tables, the order was needed for a temp table, where denormalization is obviously not an issue at all. Good point in general though.

Comment: please feel free to take a crack and drafting that 5-line query. The specific example in the question is good enough (`col_1` and `col_2` are `varchar(30)`, assume just a random 30-character strings, and the sorting order should match `ORDER BY CASE WHEN col1="" THEN "AAAAAA" ELSE col1 END, ISNULL(col2, "ZZZ")`. In English terms, think of them as 30-digit numbers in base 26, represented by upper-case-letter strings, with some NULLs that need to be treated as smallest # in case of col_1 and as largest in case of col_2.

Comment: ...BTW, this has to do with massaging existing legacy data before you rightfully ask WTF as far as the design. I worked around the issue by jumping up a level and doing this in Perl, but I'd rather do it all in SQL both for practical reasons and as a SQL learning excercise

Comment: @DVK. Comment format is too restrictive.  Responded in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution is suitable.

Add a new Field to table T, eg, ID

Then

update T set ID = number() from T order by Col1, Col2

Not sure of the version of Sybase you are using, but this works on 5.5.

A select * from T order by col1, col2 will now give the same result as 
select * from T order by ID

Cheers
AL

Comment: @Al Dwado - eh? 5.5? I have a feeling you're talking about Sybase Anywhere - Sybase Server never had version 5.5 IIRC. And sadly, the question is in the context of Sybase Server which has no "number" function (which I suspect is specific to Watcom SQL)

Comment: Yes it is Sybase Anywhere. ASE also has this function. I was unaware it was Sybase Server. Another solution is this. Create a temporary table with an autoincrement primary key, then insert into this table from the main table.

Comment: declare local temporary table TempT ( 
OrderNo integer default AutoIncrement,
col1 char(30),
col2 char(30),
primary key( OrderNo )
)
on commit preserve rows
...THEN...  
insert into TempT select  default, Col1, Col2 from T order by (whatever)